# Does there exist a sequence $b_n$ such $b_n\rightarrow0$, And $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{2^n} $ Diverges where $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k $?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Does there exist a sequence  $b_n$ such that $b_n\rightarrow0$, And

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{2^n} $ Diverges
where $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k $?

I assume there is such sequence. If $b_n\rightarrow0$ very slowly, then $a_n$ converges very quickly to $+ \infty$.

I will need some hints on finding such sequence (If one exists).

Comment: if $b_n \to 0$, then there is some $N \in \mathbb N_+$ such that for $n \ge N$ you have $|b_n| < 1$. In particular for $n$ big enough, $|a_n| \le \sum_{k=1}^N |b_k| + \sum_{k=N+1}^n |b_k| \le B_N + n$, where $B_N = \sum_{k=1}^N |b_k|$ (note that it does not depend on $n$ !). Hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|a_n|}{2^n} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{B_N + n}{2^n}$.

Comment: If $b_n$ is always positive, I suspect you'd make progress by rewriting $a_n$ as $\sum_k b_k$ and then interchanging the order of summation.

Comment: A more interesting question would be: is it possible for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^2}$ to diverge?

Answer (score 4):

$(b_n)$ is bounded. If $|b_n| \leq M$ then $|a_n| \leq nM$ and $\sum \frac n {2^{n}}$ is convergent.